# Satellites and their Trajectories

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

What is the trajectory of a body when projected with a speed greater than escape velocity?

I tried to use conservation of angular momentum in vain.
I also tried to use energy conservation, Kepler's second law but couldn't proceed. Please help me to proceed with the correct approach.

I also wanted to know what would happen in other cases.

Comment: It's a hyperbolic orbit.

Comment: Please explain it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When speed is greater than escape velocity it means the total energy is greater than zero (think of it as at infinity, it would have zero potential energy but positive kinetic energy, so total is greater than zero - and energy conservation means that's true always).

The orbit for a 1/$r^2$ force is always a conic section, always in one plane (because the direction of angular momentum is conserved) with the shape determined by total energy. For E>0 it's a hyperbola, for 0 a parabola and for less than zero an ellipse or circle. You can't do it purely from conservation laws, you have to solve the differential equation for r vs angle.

See Goldstein Classical Mechanics or most other good Classical Mechanics books. See also more than you probably ever want to know on it at the wiki article at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit